# Charset issue when scraping webpage with Python and Requests

Tags: python, encoding, character-encoding

When attempting to download a page in Chinese (appears to be gb2312 according to meta tags). I get gibberish symbols e.g. ê×××(ò) where the Chinese characters are supposed to be after I run the code below and open the file in gb2312 format in gEdit.

Here's the source code of the page in question: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/27663069655db7fd7a19 - the actual site is for educational institutes only.

My code:

```
r = requests.post("http://example.com", data=payload, cookies=cookies)
f = open('myfile.txt', 'w')
f.write(r.text.encode('gb2312',errors="ignore"))
f.close()
```

The headers for the page:

> {'content-length': '6164', 'x-powered-by': 'ASP.NET', 'date': 'Mon, 11 Mar 2013 05:11:24 GMT', 'cache-control': 'private', 'content-type': 'text/html', 'server': 'Microsoft-IIS/6.0'}

If I try to decode instead of encode, I get this error in Python:

> ```
> f.write(r.text.decode('gb2312',errors="ignore"))
> ```
>
> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 2017-2018: ordinal not in range(128)

Answer (score 1):

```
djc@enrai http $ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Jun 18 2012, 09:39:59)
[GCC 4.5.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import urllib
>>> rsp = urllib.urlopen('https://gist.github.com/anonymous/27663069655db7fd7a19/raw/836a5c55d0f87a2fa5edcc9a14097c945452f520/chinese.html').read()
>>> import chardet
>>> chardet.detect(rsp)
{'confidence': 0.99, 'encoding': 'utf-8'}
>>> rsp.decode('utf-8')
u'\n<HTML><HEAD>(snip)</BODY></HTML>\n'
```

So, don't believe the charset header, I guess?